# Regex Matching to extract a text ending with space

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, regex-look-ahead

Please help,

I need to extract a text from a long sentence

The text is as follows :

```
Current Balance: INR2,137,381.99 8/9/2020 Impaired normal
```

I would like to extract the amount from the above text and I used the regex

```
(?<=Current Balance:).+(?=/s)
```

And nothing getting..and I tried

`(?<=Current Balance:).+(?=Impaired)` and showing result :
`AED2,137,381.99 8/9/2020`

So simply I want to note the text ending with space (the date is not static) , can anyone help on this?

Comment: you should try using regex101.com to help you with your regex composition

Comment: Welcome to SO! The spec isn't really clear--what's stopping you from using `\d+\.\d+` assuming you want `381.99`?

Comment: Can you write the full expression please

Comment: I would like to get this from (?<='text1').+(?='text2'), is this possible? Text 2 is space here in input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/(?<=Current Balance:\s*)\S+/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fREKCE/1). It matches one or more non-whitespace characters after `Current Balance` phrase, possibly followed with any amount of whitespace.

```js
const string = "Current Balance: INR2,137,381.99 8/9/2020 Impaired normal";
const regex = /(?<=Current Balance:\s*)\S+/;
console.log(string.match(regex)[0])
```

Or, use capturing mechanism:

```
/Current Balance:\s*(\S+)/
```

JavaScript:

```js
const string = "Current Balance: INR2,137,381.99 8/9/2020 Impaired normal";
const regex = /Current Balance:\s*(\S+)/;
console.log(string.match(regex)[1])
```

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester  it is not working in this tool

Comment: @sreenaths Regexstorm is for .NET regex, are you using JavaScript or .NET? By the way, it seems working, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dCurrent+Balance%3a%5cs*%29%5cS%2b&i=Current+Balance%3a+INR2%2c137%2c381.99+8%2f9%2f2020+Impaired+normal).